# 0<|a|<|b|<|1| manipulated to |a| > an expression containing b

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Given that 0<|a|<|b|<|1|, is it possible to manipulate this to get an inequality in the form:  $$|a|> |expression(b)|$$  , such that:

- $expression(b)$ is an expression that contains the variable b
- the $expression(b)$ contains no mentions of a
- everything is an element of the reals

Comment: I wanted an expression of b in absolute value.

Comment: Isn't this impossible in general because in the case $a=0$, there can't be an expression $p(b)$ such that $|a|>|p(b)|$? Or is it given that $a\ne 0$?

Comment: You clearly ask something which is *always* impossible.

Comment: it is given that $a\neq0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is possible, but only if you allow for the expression of $b$ to always equal $0$. You see, $|a|$ can be arbitrarily small, so any expression $p(b)$ satisfying $|a|>|p(b)|$ for all $a\ne 0$ must be equal to $0$. Think about it: if $p(b)\ne 0$ for some $b$, then we can choose $a=\frac{p(b)}{2}$ that doesn't satisfy your equation.

The only possible general solution is $p(b)=0$ for all $b$, so if you require the expression to actually contain $b$ in it, you can just artificially inject $b$ into the expression by defining $p(b)=b-b$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the given that $a \neq 0 $

Comment: @IonSme Okay. I will modify my answer accordingly.